# How to collect the path of a file from a class library's dll?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, filepath, class-library

I have a class library as a project, and several other projects (Windows service, web app etc.) that uses this class library.

I added a text file to the class library project. However, I am am unable to identify its path from class library's code, because other projects copies this library as a .dll to their own directories, and when they use it's functions, they return their own path instead.

Is it possible to retrieve this path? ("The path of the project that made you create this .dll") Or I have to copy this text file to any other project that uses this library? I am open for new ideas too.

Comment: Any reason not to use relative paths? That way if you move the project around you won't have to modify that path.

Comment: @CristiFati It is a production project so I am not allowed to pick my paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer: It is not possible. Even you don't copy the dll, as you expect the .dll you gathered should be a standalone file. You should copy it by hand, or put the file as repository inside .dll. I solved it by storing the filepath in somewhere.